# tmux OSX 10.8.3 show ipaddress

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, tmux

I am trying to display my ipaddress and the date on the right side of my tmux status line. I have the following command:

```
set -g status-right "#[fg-cyan]#(ifconfig | awk '$1 == "inet" { print $2 }') #[fg=cyan]%d %b %R"
```

It is displaying the date but not the ipaddress. I am not getting any error from Tmux so I am not sure what is going wrong.

Any help is apprecited!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the value that actually ends up being set:

```
tmux show-option -g | grep status-right
```

I expect that you will find that there are no double quotes around `inet`. The double quote parsing does not consider the `#()` syntax as special (unlike `"$()"` in shells, where you can simply use double quotes inside the command substitution). Thus, the parsing is done in three pieces:

- `"#[fg-cyan]#(ifconfig | awk '$1 == "`
- `inet`
- `" { print $2 }') #[fg=cyan]%d %b %R"`

These are concatenated into this:

```
#[fg-cyan]#(ifconfig | awk '$1 == inet { print $2 }') #[fg=cyan]%d %b %R
```

As an *awk* program, this ends up checking `$1` against an unset variable named `inet` instead of the literal string `"inet"`; *awk* will probably not complain, but no lines will ever match.

You can escape the double quotes to let them pass into the final string:

```
set -g status-right "#[fg-cyan]#(ifconfig | awk '$1 == \"inet\" { print $2 }') #[fg=cyan]%d %b %R"
```

When I set this, I just see `127.0.0.1` though; you might want to add a `|tail -1` to use the last line instead of the first.

Two other items:

- you have `[fg-` instead of `[fg=`, and
- since you are specifying the same color in both place, you can probably just omit the second one.

Thus:

```
set -g status-right "#[fg=cyan]#(ifconfig | awk '$1 == \"inet\" { print $2 }'|tail -1) %d %b %R"
```